# Save Attributed Text to Parse in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am creating a basic note taking though parse using Swift. I want to save the attributed text to parse, but I can't figure out how. I've look online and I was not successful. Does anyone have any ideas? Here is my code:

NotesTableViewController.swift:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NotesTableViewCell

let object: PFObject = self.notObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

cell.masterCell?.text = object["title"] as? String
cell.masterTextLabel?.text = object["text"] as? String

return cell
```

addNoteTableController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.colorPicker.alpha = 0
self.fontPicker.alpha = 0

if (self.object != nil) {
    self.titleField?.text = self.object["title"] as? String
    self.textView?.text = self.object["text"] as? String
}else {
    self.object = PFObject(className: "Note")
    }
}

@IBAction func saveAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
self.object["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
self.object["title"] = self.titleField?.text
self.object["text"] = self.textView?.text

self.object.saveEventually { (sucess, error) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
    }else {
        print(error?.userInfo)
    }
}

self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Note: Please be very specific in your answers. Don't just give me a link. I really need the code written for me at this point.... THANKS!!!!!

Comment: @Wain what do you mean?

Comment: Are you aware of `PFFile` ?

Comment: @Wain do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try something, that's how you learn, then ask if you have problems but show your new code

Comment: One of the thing I tried was saving it to parse as a NSAttributesString, but it didn't work @Wain

Comment: Please help me @Wain

Comment: Archive the attributed string to data and save in a PFFile

Comment: @Wain How the heck do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have an `NSAttributedString`, which supports coding, so you can use an `NSKeyedArchiver` to create an `NSData` instance representing the raw attributed string. This includes the text and all of the formatting.

Using this data you can create a `PFFile` and save it, you also need to associate this file with another object in your parse store so you can get it back later. When you do you can get the `NSData` from it and use an `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to unpack it back into an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Ok... Can you please give me the exact code that I should use?

Comment: I could really use ur help

Comment: have you looked at the interfaces for the classes i've told you about? writing software is about solving problems, which means it's about thinking - a solution on a plate isn't thinking or learning...

Comment: I've been thinking and learning for weeks. I looked into the pffile idea but was quite able to get it. Please please help

Comment: get the data by archiving the attributed string first. then create a file. then look at what to do with the file. then look at the reverse. break it down.

Comment: I got that. I'm just not sure how to execute it

Comment: update your question with all your new code and explain what doesn't work

Comment: I've deleted it all. And tried something else. And when that didn't work, I deleted it. I honestly don't remember. Listen, I really just want to fix the problem because then i can move on to another part of my app and have fun. I just need to be done with this issue. Please can you help me